# Magento 2 cron error 'Process went away'

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron, cronjobs

I created custom cron job which is working fine on localhost and was working initially on the server as well but now on the server, it is getting scheduled but status changes from "pending" to "error" and message appeared is "Process went away at 2020-1-10 13:05:05". Please let me know if somebody experienced this, the reason for it?

[image]

It is working fine on local server whereas on staging rest of the cron jobs are also working. What is this error due to?

Comment: make sure that you have enough memory on your staging server or try to run cron with memory as following : php -d memory_limit=1G /magento_root/bin/magento cron:run >/dev/null

Answer (score 1):

As @Oscprofessionals mentioned already in his comment: This is an issue with your PHP memory_limit.

Check your PHP memory_limit:

```
$ php -i | grep memory_limit
```

You can try to run the cronjob manually via CLI (with the [Cronjob Manager](https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager) installed) and check the output:

```
bin/magento cronmanager:run your_cronjob_code
```

Then you will most likely see an error output that memory is exhausted. Raise yor memory_limit and try again.